# Attaching link on facebook wall - missing image

Tags: facebook

I have og:image properly pointing to the correct image, but when I try to attach link on wall to page, no image is displayed, and title is truncated. However, if I submit the page to facebook linter, it comes back with no errors, and then the second time I attach link, it works fine. Does anyone know what is going on?